# Why do I get this error: Property 'latex_code' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Omit<LaTeXBoXProps, "latex_code">'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

In the following code from my react project written in Typescript, I made an connected component.
However, it seems that the connected component gets rid one of my props from my original component.
How can this happen, and how do I fix it?

The error message when I was using the connected component while passing my props:

```
Type '{ extract: any; latex_code: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Omit<LaTeXBoXProps, "latex_code">'.
  Property 'latex_code' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Omit<LaTeXBoXProps, "latex_code">'.t
```

My code:

```
type LaTeXBoXProps = {
    latex_code: string,
    extract: (a: string)=>void
}

const LaTeXBox = (props : LaTeXBoXProps) => {
    
    const [state, _] = useState(props);

    function clickEvent(): void{
       myStore.dispatch({
         type: "REFRESH",
         value: state.latex_code
       });
    }

      return (
        <span className="TeXBox"
             onClick={clickEvent}>
            <MathComponent tex={state.latex_code} display={false}/>
        </span>
      )
}

const updateTeXBox = (_latex_code: string) => {
  return {
      latex_code: _latex_code
  }
}

export default connect(updateTeXBox)(LaTeXBox);
```

Comment: `const LaTeXBox: FunctionComponent< LaTeXBoXProps > = (props) => {` try this, import `FunctionComponent` from React

Comment: No. It doesn't work.

Comment: show me how you modified it

Comment: Just add the import on the top